# Help me fix my toilet

Tags: riddle

> It's always the same.
>   There isn't any room left
>   to dispose of the waste
>   due to the lack of a bend.
>   Always the same.
>   Are there lots of socks in there?
>   Or just a couple?
>   Or just one?

What am I missing here, and how can I fix my toilet?

Hint #1

> Each line defines an element of a sequence. There is one element missing (or two, depending on your opinion), and the missing element can help fix the problem. Some lines aren't very helpful and some are. The next hint will say which lines are the most revealing. Happy plumbing!

Hint #2

> Solving any two of lines 3, 4 and 7 will probably lead to solving the whole thing. Line 2 is also fairly helpful. Lines 3 and 7 should be considered in the context of the rest of the puzzle. Lines 2 and 4 can be considered out of context.

Hint #3

> In each of these cases, think of a single word answer. Don't think too deeply, the answers are very simple. Line 3: How would you normally dispose of waste, in the context of a toilet? Line 4: How would you describe something that doesn't have any bends? Line 7: How would you normally describe a quantity of socks?

Comment: You're missing a plumber?

Comment: No room to dispose of the waster? In the toilet? Now that's a disturbing image!

Comment: That's why I need your help!

Comment: socks in your toilet? mmmh that is strange

Comment: If there is only 1 sock, you are missing a sock.

Comment: OT: Belongs on DIY.stackexchange.com

Comment: A urinal maybe?

Comment: Since nobody has made any real progress, hint #1 has appeared.

Comment: @Statman can we assume this is actually a toilet and not some metaphor?

Comment: @DavidFoong I will just say that user662852's answer is in the right "style".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to the third hint I got it.
The missing thing is :

> Straight flush

Because

> Every line refers to a poker combination, in descending value order

- It's always the same.

  > Four of a kind
- There isn't any room left

  > Full house
- to dispose of the waste

  > Flush
- due to the lack of a bend.

  > Straight
- Always the same.

  > Three of a kind
- Are there lots of socks in there?

  > Two pair
- Or just a couple?

  > One pair
- Or just one?

  > High card

Comment: Wow!!! I had left poker couple of weeks ago otherwise ;P

Answer (score 9):

### A Totally Incorrect Answer #1

*But something neat I found XD*

You are missing

> One syllable in the fifth line and four syllables in the eighth line. One you add these back in, you'll get 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7 syllables in each line :P

### A Totally Incorrect Answer #2

*No room to dispose of the waster? In the toilet?*

You are missing

> A bigger toilet hole. Tools needed: a jackhammer and a pair of goggles and earmuffs.

***Note: Yes, I agree with @ChrisCudmore...this question definitely belongs on DIY Stackexchange***

Comment: LOL. Idk if I should down vote because its spam or upvote because its funny (currently upvoted). Also debating whether to flag....

Comment: But again, I'm not supposed to *encourage* low quality posts

Comment: @North Lol I'm pretty sure it's going to be deleted soon so yolo might as well

Comment: How about the OP just doesnt flush socks down the toilet

Comment: Thats the spirit!

Comment: Totally incorrect answer #1: Interesting discovery! Completely unintentional, of course. +1 for investigative skills.

Comment: Totally incorrect answer #2: It would certainly solve the problem! Not what I'm looking for though, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 3):

It's always the same.

> Entropy is zero

There isn't any room left

> Either it's the beginning of time or a black hole at the heat death of the universe

to dispose of the waste

> It's a black hole, of these two possibilies, to dispose of the "waste".  Though maybe this is the first "wasted clue", so it might be poetic or lateral thinking, and here we are: this clue is its own disposed waste.

due to the lack of a bend.

> Scratch that, time is like an arrow and moves forward - it's the beginning of time.

Always the same.

> Definitely the beginning of time

Are there lots of socks in there?

> Well, ok, I guess it's a black hole after all.  And/or this is another misdirecting clue.

Or just a couple?

> Again, a couple choices, beginning of time or black hole; another misdirecting extra clue.

Or just one?

> Beginning of time.  One universe.  Final answer: You need the Big Bang to clear your metaphysical toilet -  and when your 24 hour plumber finally answers the service call for your physical toilet, there will also be a big bang of sorts, and there *will* be an increase in entropy.

Comment: Well, you certainly took the whole thing into account! While my toilet is certainly beginning to feel like a black hole, the real answer is much more down to Earth.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer?

> You need to do the laundry?

"...Lack of a bend..."

> Laundry baskets dont have bends like toilets

"Are there lots of socks in there?"

> The number of socks also goes down like you are emptying the laundry basket

Comment: I probably do need to do the laundry, but that doesn't help fixing the toilet. In the correct answer, every line plays a role.